# Python 2.7: reading from .txt to matrix

Tags: python, matrix

this is my first post :)

My question is how can i read binary array from a .txt file to a matrix? For example i have such a file:

```
0000010101010
1101010101000
0010010010000
0000000000000
.
.
.
```

and i like to copy data to a matrix like this:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],  
 [1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0], 
 [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],  
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

My problem is that i'm not using any separator for bits (a part of \n for each line).

Comment: `matrix = [[int(char) for char in line] for line in f]`?

Comment: i think he is asking for a nested list

Comment: @Optimuskck Jon's solution will produce that.

Comment: @Cyber yap now its fine.

Comment: @ jonrsharpe it gives me "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:"

Comment: You need to `.strip` the newline character `'\n'`

Comment: You must have a character other than 1 or 0 in your input.  @jonrsharpe: Your solution, though short, should be an answer. Anyone: Is there a reason that python, in general, does not include the invalid value in this kind of exception message (*ValueError: Invalid literal "Z" for int() with base 10* for instance)?

Comment: @LarryLustig because the invalid value is a newline, so appears as `''`. Also, my answer is very similar to that which Vishnu has added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:-

```
    with open('new.txt') as f:
        l = [map(int, line.strip()) for line in f]
    print l
```

output:-

```
>>> 
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: That creates a list of lists, each of which holds a single string, which isn't terribly helpful.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for reminding me my error, i updated the code, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You  can create `Matrix` using `numpy` download from [scipy.org](http://www.scipy.org)

Example of `Matrix` [Here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)

```
import numpy
file=open("m.txt",'r')
m=[]
s=[]
for i in file.readlines():
 for j in i:
   if j!='\n':
      s.append(j)
 m.append(s)
 s=[]

matrix=numpy.matrix(m)
```

The output Shows like That :

```
    matrix([['0','0','0','0','0','1','0','1','0','1','0','1','0'],
    ['1','1','0','1','0','1','0','1','0','1','0','0','0'],
    ['0', '0','1','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0'],
    ['0','0','0','0','0','0', '0', '0','0','0','0','0','0']], 
   dtype='|S1')
```